# How to create a table in mysql with unicode string as table name?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

table_name: Jm™–Í€hÀÂ}#’ÇÊµf‹xãÈÜû,ÀD^Ð*

I want to create a table with table_name in mysql5. 
ID,NAME are the column names given in the table. Is it possible to create?

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\x0fJm\ufffd\x12\ufffd\u0340\x11h\ufffd\ufffd}#\ufffd\ufffd\u02b5\x0cf\ufffdx\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd,\ufffdD^\ufffd* (ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(10),' at line 1")

Comment: I want to encrypt the table name before storing it in the cloud server, so that the security is enhanced (Time factor is eliminated) and I have the metadata to decrypt it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After puzzling alot, I simply converted the entire string into BASE32 format because its character set contains the values accepted as table name in MySQL but there should be a restriction on the length of the output string or else "=" will be appended at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest that you take the HEX() of the encrypted string.  This will avoid any nasty characters that could cause fatal errors -- such as space, zero byte, slash, backslash, quotes, backtic, ...

I checked on BASE64, but it has a potentially serious problem because it includes "/"

Comment: If we consider the hex value of the string table_name, which is mentioned in the question then the length of the output string is longer than 64 bytes which is not allowed as table name in sql

Comment: You need to give up on something -- either some bytes or length.

Comment: Thanks Rick James, for the idea of BASE64. Instead of converting it into BASE64 I have converted it into BASE32 by which i have avodied the "/" in string.